# Why the .so file always smaller than the .a file?(the source is identical.)

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I use a .a file in my project,when I use the source files in the project and the .a file to generate a .so file, I found the generated .so file is smaller than the .a file,

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Specific compiler? GCC?

Comment: Which `.a` file you're referring to in particular? The stub that's generated for a `.so`, or a static library generated for the same source code?

Comment: Both the .a and the .so file contain code.  Consider panicking only when the .so file gets *bigger* than the .a file, you then have to figure out where that extra code came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link stage (which generates the shared object file) will trim out unused functions etc. and perform other compaction.

The compilation phase (which generates the .a) will not.

Comment: I'm not sure that fully explains it.